# Typical CSS menu dropdown hover issue with iPad

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, css

We're having a common issue with hover states and CSS menus on the iPad. Because it doesn't recognize hover states it's not allowing a selection.

We've tried most of the common workarounds like `onClick="return true"` and using jQuery to create a dynamic hover class to replicate :hover and a few others, which I've removed now to clean the code a bit. I'm sure we're missing something that should be obvious.

Any help pointing me in the right direction on this would be greatly appreciated.

Link: iar.suissamesser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the menu, correct? What I do in this case, is add another line to my css `:hover` selector. The idea is this, on click, add a class to the `#nav` like '`btn1`. This would also require you to add a class to your list-items.
CSS

```
#nav li:hover > ul,
#nav.btn1 li.btn1 > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="clearfix btn1" id="nav">
  <li class="btn1"><a href="http://iar.suissamesser.com/about-us/campus">ABOUT US</a><br />
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://iar.suissamesser.com/about-us/campus">Campus</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://iar.suissamesser.com/about-us/history-mission">History &amp; Mission</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="btn2"><a href="http://iar.suissamesser.com/parents/accreditation-and-licenses" >PARENTS</a><br />
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://iar.suissamesser.com/parents/accreditation-and-licenses">Accreditation and Licenses</a></li>
```

JS

```
$("#nav > li > a").on("click", toggleNav);
var toggleNav = function(evt){
  var clicked = $(this).parent().attr('class');
  $("#nav").removeClass("btn1 btn2 btn3 btn4 ...").addClass(clicked);
  evt.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the issue. Thanks so much -- we'll try this out.

Comment: So each top level item would needs it's own named class btn1,btn2,etc.?

Comment: Correct. Anything that fires the hover state, so in the case, all the first level `li`s. Then you can just toggle a class in the parent `ul#nav` that selects each option. If you are targeting only modern browsers, which mobile only falls under, you can also use some `nth-child` selectors.

Comment: Just tried the CSS part. So let me check I fully understand. Use the jQuery hover solution I reference in my questions combined with this CSS to toggle the correct btn# class? Sounds right.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't need the jQuery hover. The hover events should work fine via css. But I'd use click events for ipad

Comment: I'm sorry I must be missing something, I have the code in the footer and the CSS in place for the About Uu link. Now it shows by default in the iPad and the click works. Should I add in display:none; inline?

Comment: When the page loads, the `#nav` shouldn't have any of the button classes `btn1`. You toggle them on click. All the click does is toggle the `class`.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the example here http://www.hnldesign.nl/work/code/mouseover-hover-on-touch-devices-using-jquery/

It's pretty straight forward from there.
Good Luck,

Comment: Thanks! The tutorial at that link is great.

Answer (score 0):

Include the below code in a footer file

```
$('body').on('touchstart.dropdown', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) {
e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I still had issues implementing the approved answer so much thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is a late late late response, but.

you dont actually have to use any kind of jquery or code, you just need to confuse or override the ipad logic in the css.

try this in your css

```
.navigation li ul
{
display:none;
}
.navigation li:hover ul
{
display:block;  
}
.navigation > li:hover
{
background-color:#000;  
}
```

as i understand, this stops the ipad cascading into the li and you hitting the a href because you did a hover on the li, but, when the sub menu is open, the a becomes the next responder because the li already has a hover state active.

this was discovered by accident.

html would be like this

```
<ul class="navigation">
<li><a href="http://www.google.com">test link</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link</a></li>
</ul>
<li><a href="#www.google.com">test link</a>
<li><a href="#www.google.com">test link</a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to get this to work quite well without Javascript.

The key pieces of CSS:

```css
/* hide submenu by default */
.nav .submenu {
  display: none; 
}
/* show submenu on :hover and :focus-within */
.nav li:hover .submenu, .nav li:focus-within .submenu {
  display: block; 
}
```

To get the `:hover` to work correctly on iPad, you need to add a `tabindex` to your top-level menu items:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li tabindex="0">
    Menu Item
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>...</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And then to be able to *close* the menu, you need to add a tabindex to the `<body>` tag also:

```
<body tabindex="0">
```

The good thing about this approach is that it also allows keyboard navigation, and is good for accessibility.