# CSS drop down menu is not working on iOS devices

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Why does my CSS dropdown menu work on Android and all PC browsers, but not iOS devices?

```
.mainHeaderBtns ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: How can you hover on mobile?

Comment: Hover works on Android.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typical CSS menu dropdown hover issue with iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239912/typical-css-menu-dropdown-hover-issue-with-ipad)

Comment: @SimonEast This question was almost 6 years ago and has an accepted answer lol

Comment: Yes, apologies. That text you see in my comment above is inserted automatically by StackExchange when flagging threads as duplicates. I probably should have edited it, but too late to edit now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of my tests, for a dropdown menus, make sure the `<a href="#">` element is visible and clickable on the page, I have made a simple demo and it works fine.

```css
.nav > li > ul {
  display: none;
}
.nav > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu item</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Sub item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

For any element, Apple <sup>1</sup> recommends to add `onclick = "void(0)"` I also found `onclick="return false;"`or `onclick=""` all works.

```css
div span {
  display: none;
}
div:hover span {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="void(0)">Howdy <span>mates!</span></div>
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html</sub>

Comment: Apple at one time recommended `onclick="void(0)"` to make something a touch-target, which I still use and seems to still work fine for my 3-level dropdown navigation menus on my iPad.  I can't find the reference at the moment so I can't say if that's still what they recommend.

Comment: @StephenP I found the reference on Safari web content guide, and updated above, thanks!

Comment: I actually figured this out right before you posted this (I used onClick="return true"). Thanks for your answer, though!

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get this to work quite well using standards-compliant code, *without* Javascript hacks.

The key pieces of CSS:

```css
/* hide submenu by default */
.nav .submenu {
  display: none; 
}
/* show submenu on :hover and :focus-within */
.nav li:hover .submenu, .nav li:focus-within .submenu {
  display: block; 
}
```

To get the `:hover` to work correctly on iPad, you need to add a `tabindex` to your top-level menu items:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li tabindex="0">
    Menu Item
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>...</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And then to be able to *close* the menu, you need to add a tabindex to the `<body>` tag also:

```
<body tabindex="0">
```

The good thing about this approach is that it also allows keyboard navigation, which is good for accessibility.