# Dropdown menu for iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, drop-down-menu

I have the code below for a drop down menu which works very well in Safari, Firefox, Chrome. There's a list of links, but one of them is a drop down. The code works on Chrome on Android, but I have no success at making this work on Safari + Chrome on iOS. First, when I click on "Dropdown", it takes me to dropdown link 1 directly. There's no hover, even though the parent "Dropdown" isn't a link. Can somebody point how to fix this issue?

```
       <li><a href="smth.html">smth</a></li>
       <li><a href="info.html">info</a></li>
       <div class="dropdown" onclick="">
       <li>Dropdown</li>  
       <div class="dropdown-content">
       <ul><a href="dropdown.html">dropdown link 1</a></ul>
       <ul><a href="workshops.html">dropdown link 2</a></ul>
       </div>
```

CSS below:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Is this for hybrid app or for native app ?

Comment: native @TejaNandamuri

Comment: looks like hybrid to me. How are you testing this code ?

Comment: do you mean manual testing? I just open the webapp on chrome + safari on iOS and I can't make it work. Seems like hover is a bit of an issue for iOS?

Comment: Found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687656/css-drop-down-menu-is-not-working-on-ios-devices