# CSS drop down menu on iOS devices does not disappear when clicking outside

Tags: css, ios, menu, hover, dropdown

Thanks again for this very simple solution for making CSS dropdown menus work also on iOS (just add onclick = "void(0)"):
[CSS drop down menu is not working on iOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687656/css-drop-down-menu-is-not-working-on-ios-devices)

But there is another iOS specific problem: When you open the dropdown menu and then want to close it by clicking or tipping somewhere else outside, on Windows and Android, it disappears. But not on iOS.

Does maybe anyone know the solution to this problem?

Comment: I posted a solution in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69225956/195835

Answer (score 0):

Now I found a very simple and working solution:
[Dropdown menu css / js on Ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555187/dropdown-menu-css-js-on-ipad)

Just add the following JavaScript code to the body:

```html
<script>
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {});
</script>
```